# How can I convert python class with slots to dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using class with slots to reduce the memory which the instance will occupy. Now, how can I convert a slot instance to dictionary ?

The slot class look like this :

```
class Foo(object):
       __slots__ = ['x','y','z']
       def __init__(self):
           self.x = 1
           self.y = 2 
           self.z = 3
```

I expect something like this:

```
y = Foo()
y.__dict__
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome, a dictionary with the slot names as keys and the attributes as values?

Comment: Please show us the slots class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `__slots__` attribute plus [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) in a dictionary comprehension:

```
{
    s: getattr(obj, s)
    for s in {
        s
        for cls in type(obj).__mro__
        for s in getattr(cls, '__slots__', ())
    }
    if hasattr(obj, s)
}
```

which collects the slot names from all base classes and skips any attributes not set.

Alternative, setting missing attributes to `None`:

```
{
    s: getattr(obj, s, None)
    for s in {
        s
        for cls in type(obj).__mro__
        for s in getattr(cls, '__slots__', ())
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __slots__ = ('bar', 'spam')
... 
>>> obj = Foo()
>>> obj.bar = 42
>>> {s: getattr(obj, s) for s in {s for cls in type(obj).__mro__ for s in getattr(cls, '__slots__', ())} if hasattr(obj, s)}
{'bar': 42}
>>> {s: getattr(obj, s, None) for s in {s for cls in type(obj).__mro__ for s in getattr(cls, '__slots__', ())}}
{'spam': None, 'bar': 42}
```

You can even make that a property of the class and `vars()` will make use of it:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __slots__ = ('bar', 'spam')
...     @property
...     def __dict__(self):
...         return {
...             s: getattr(self, s)
...             for s in {
...                 s
...                 for cls in type(self).__mro__
...                 for s in getattr(cls, '__slots__', ())
...             }
...             if hasattr(self, s)
...         }
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar = 42
>>> f.__dict__
{'bar': 42}
>>> f.spam = 'eggs'
>>> f.__dict__
{'spam': 'eggs', 'bar': 42}
>>> vars(f)
{'spam': 'eggs', 'bar': 42}
>>> f.hello = 'world'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'hello'
```

Comment: If I overload the `__getattr__` method, this solution is broken. In that situation, how to access the properties defined in `__slots__`?

Comment: @livingzhang: `__getattr__` is only called for attributes that don't exist. As long as you still raise `AttributeError` in `__getattr__` for attributes it doesn't support, the above will work just fine.

Comment: This doesn't work well with inheritence. If the slotted class inherits a non-slotted one, the dict wont contain the inheritted attributes. Also if a non-slotted class inherits from a slotted one with the __dict__ property, its dict will be empty

Comment: Then how do you make it work with inheritance? @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon

Comment: @NicolásRivera not sure, short of examining the mro for all classes with slots and combining all the slots with __dict__ (if it exists) I can't really think of a neat solution

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon inheriting from a class with slots but not providing a new `__slots__` is completely pointless. The point of having slots is to save memory (`__dict__` dictionaries waste memory, relatively speaking). If a subclass has no slots it’ll be given a `__dict__` slot again and so wastes the effort of using slots for the base classes. There is no point in trying to make this answer work in such a scenario, it’s a waste of time and memory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters even if a slotted class extends another slotted class, the derived class's slots wouldn't include the base's. Also, the base class might be from another library so one may not have control over whether it user slots or not. Or perhaps i'm writing the base in a library and don't want to restrict or rely on users to use or not use slots in their derived classes. I'm just saying that there are many possible scenarios, not all of which are nonsensical, and it would be nice to have a neat solution that works in every case (whether or not it's a waste of memory)

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon: that `__slots__` doesn't include the slots of base classes is a fair point; I've added an inner set comprehension over `type(self).__mro__` to address this. It's a general drawback of the `__slots__` system that it's easy to forget to use `__slots__` in subclasses. There are solutions for that (e.g. validating subclasses in `__init_subclass__`), but that doesn't make it *possible* to provide a generic `__dict__` property for those cases. If you don't use `__slots__`, then a `__dict__` slot is added to the class and any custom `__dict__` property is shadowed.

Comment: Adding a custom `__dict__` property probably has too many weird compatibility issues to be worthwhile. They tried that with `namedtuple` back in the day, setting `__dict__ = property(_asdict)`, and took it out when they found it caused too many weird compatibility issues. I'd probably just make it an `asdict()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna read the props in slots, and store it into a dictionary, the dictionary comprehension through the property `__slots__` is the way to go:

```
my_dict = {slot: getattr(obj, slot) for slot in obj.__slots__}
```