# converting a subclass with __slots__ to json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, inheritance, flask

I am a total noob in Python and just couldn't help myself but did it again and dreamed of something I just couldn't achieve.

I wanted to have a class, which can be instantiated as such:

```
my_class = MyClass(**params)
```

and be consumed as such, in Flask:

```
jsonify(my_class)
```

The expected outcome would be a JSON:

```
{ "key" : "value", ... }
```

Now, the implementation of MyClass is,

```
class MyClas(NamedMutableSequence, Document):
    __slots__ = (
        'key_1',
        'key_2',
        'key_3'
    )

def __init__(self, **params):
    NamedMutableSequence.__init__(self, **params)
    Document.__init__(self, 'myclass')

def save(self):
    self._db_col.update({'key_1': self.key_1}, {'key_2': self.key_2, 'key_3': self.key_3})
```

By now, you are wondering what `NamedMutableSequence` and `Document` are...

```
    class NamedMutableSequence(Sequence):
        ___slots__ = ()

        def __init__(self, *positional_values, **keyword_values):
            subclass_propeties = self.__slots__
            for key in subclass_propeties:
                setattr(self, key, keyword_values.get(key))

            if positional_values:
                for key, value in zip(subclass_propeties, positional_values):
                    setattr(self, key, value)

        def __str__(self):
            values = ', '.join('%s=%r' % (key, getattr(self, key)) for key in self.__slots__)
            return '%s(%s)' % (clsname, values)

        __repr__ = __str__

        def __getitem__(self, item):
            return getattr(self, item)

        def __setitem__(self, item, value):
            return setattr(self, item, value)

        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.__slots__)
```

Admittedly, I just copied someone's solution to a mutable namedtuple for this base class and fixed `__getitem__` & `__setitem__` to allow `my_class.key_1 = 'some value'`

```
class Document():
    __slots__ = ('_db_col')

    def __init__(self, collection):
        self._db_col = mongo_db[collection]
```

This is just what I spew out in attempt for a base class which I will be using throughout my model classes for db connection.

This is, in my opinion, where it starts I got too over myself and just created a mess. Because no matter what I try, I can't stop raising `TypeError: {string value of my_class} is not JSON serializable`.

To make matters worse, when I try to `dict(my_class)`, I get a shiny `attributes must be string` error raised on `getattr()`.

I would still like to keep the base classes and I still need to make it JSON serializable.

How can I save myself?

Comment: Why are you using `__slots__` here at all? That's an optimisation and should only be used rarely.

Comment: @DanielRoseman well, it may be an anti-pattern of trying to over-optimize now that you mention it. But it had happened already and I think it is still worth pursuing a solution even if for educational purpose only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer finally, and the solution was found from another stackoverflow post ([How can I convert python class with slots to dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682774/how-can-i-convert-python-class-with-slots-to-dictionary))

What I did was just to add another method on the `NamedMutableSequence` as such:

```
def json(self):
    return {key : getattr(self, key, None) for key in self.__slots__}
```

and just call it when I need a JSON parsable dictionary, as such:

```
my_class = MyClass(**params)
jsonify(my_class.json())
```

Comment: You should probably implement an `items()` method that returns an iterator, it would use less memory